# How to use grep to output result of each line?

Tags: awk, sed, grep

I have a text file with a random number of lines.
Lines look like this:

```
neededLine [text1] sometext [text2] sometext [text3]
sometext [text4] sometext [text5] sometext [text6]
neededLine [text7] sometext [text8] sometext [text9]
```

I have a grep command in shell, which takes lines with 'neededLine' word, and then extracts everything inside brackets. 
Command looks like this:
`grep 'neededLine' |grep -Po '(?<=\[).*?(?=\])' | tr '\n' ' '`

So my output looks like this:

```
text1 text2 text3 text7 text8 text9
```

If I remove `tr`, output starts with a new line for every single word:

```
text1 
text2 
text3
...
```

How do I get an output, which prints the result in one separate line for every single input line? It should look like

```
text1 text2 text3 
text7 text8 text9
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With sed:

```
sed '/neededLine/!d
s/[^[]*\[//
s/\][^[]*$//
s/\][^[]*\[/ /g' file
```

Comment: The `sed` solution is perfectly worked, I was even able to add some further commands within one sed. Entire script shrank by 3 times! Many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Could you please try following, written and tested with shown samples in GNU `awk`.

```
awk '
/neededLine/{
  while(match($0,/\[[^]]*/)){
    val=(val?val OFS:"")substr($0,RSTART+1,RLENGTH-1)
    $0=substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH+1)
  }
  print val
  val=""
}
'  Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '                                                       ##Starting awk program from here.
/neededLine/{                                               ##Checking if a line starts with neededLine then do following.
  while(match($0,/\[[^]]*/)){                               ##Using regex in match function till its result comes true in current line.
    val=(val?val OFS:"")substr($0,RSTART+1,RLENGTH-1)       ##Creating var val whose value keep concatenate its own value and its value is sub-string of current line.
    $0=substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH+1)                          ##Assigning sub-string value to current line which will be rest of the line after matching above.
  }
  print val                                                 ##Printing val here.
  val=""                                                    ##Nullifying val here.
} 
' Input_file                                                ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Answer (score 2):

With `perl`:

```
$ perl -lne 'print join " ", /\[\K.*?(?=])/g if /neededLine/' ip.txt
text1 text2 text3
text7 text8 text9
```

- `if /neededLine/` only lines containing `neededLine`
- `/\[\K.*?(?=])/g` extract contents between `[` and `]`

  - `\K` is helpful to discard text matched until that point
  - you can also use `/\[\K[^]]+(?=])/g`
- `join " "` to combine the matched portions with a space
- `-l` option removes the record separator and adds it back at the end of `print` statement, helps to get a newline character in this case

Another solution with `GNU awk`

```
$ awk -v FPAT='\\[[^]]+]' '/neededLine/{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)
                           gsub(/^.|.$/, "", $i); print}' ip.txt
text1 text2 text3
text7 text8 text9
```